# Restrict some actions, _remap function, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make some actions available only for logged in users.
I've tried to restrict some by this code:

```
function _remap($method)
    {
        $restricted = array('update_rating', 'delete_post');
        if( ! $this->session->userdata('logged_in') && in_array($method, $restricted))
        {
           echo 'Log in, please'; 
        }
        else {
           $this->$method();
        }
    }
```

**But $this->$method() didn't receive parameters which was sent in url. What to do?**
*I want to make some actions avalible only for logged in users.*

Comment: `_remap` is a special function to modify the calling function from a url...if you want to restrict access to a function via a url, then you must append an underscore `_foo($vars)` - this can only be called within your controller (not via the url). clarify maybe? your code otherwise looks ok. in the above, whatever function is called, `_remap` will compare what was requested and attempt to call it based on your condition.

Comment: Nope, I want to make some functions allowed only for logged users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restrict logged in users for an entire controller use something like:

```
function __construct(){

  if(!is_logged_in){
    redirect('user/login');
  }

}
```

Or do the same if you need to restrict a specific method:

```
function restricted_function(){

   if(!is_logged_in){
     redirect('user/login');
   }

 }
```

This requires that you have an is_logged_in variable set before the controller is called.

I use a a MY_controller that checks for a logged in session that all controllers inherit.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should not be using this patter of development for creating a user login. You should simply do the check in the constructor of the class that you're calling, and use $this->router->method to see what method the user is trying to access. Check that against an array of methods that require login, then check to see if the user is logged in or not. If one of the conditions is false, redirect to login page, or else, continue with execution of the call. Sample implementation below:

```
Class XYZ extends Controller{

    function __construct() {
        parent::controller();
        $protected_methods = array('method_1', 'method_2');

        if(in_array($this->router->method, $protected_methods)){
            // check if user is logged in
            if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
                redirect('/login');
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't send any parameters to it.

You should give all the parameters you need the $method to evaluate.

```
function _remap($method)
{
    $restricted = array('update_rating', 'delete_post');
    if( ! $this->session->userdata('logged_in') && in_array($method, $restricted))
    {
       echo 'Log in, please'; 
    }
    else
    {
        $params = get_func_get_args();
        $this->$method($params);
    }
}
```

Note that the methods would now receive and array of the parameters.

Comment: Good idea! So, there is no way to work with regular function arguments without array of parameters?